# Is there any other way to get crashed application name from EventLog using C#

Tags: c#, event-log

I am using below C# code to get crashed application name from EventLog,

```
EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
var entries = log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Reverse().Where(x => (UInt16)x.InstanceId == 1000 && x.EntryType.ToString() == "Error" && x.Source == "Application Error").Select(x => new
            {
                x.Message,
                x.TimeGenerated

            }).ToList();
```

The problem is `x.Message` contains a big string with application name (`wmiprvse.exe`, example below),

```
Faulting application name: wmiprvse.exe, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d443
Faulting module name: svrenumapi100.dll, version: 2009.100.1600.1, time stamp: 0x4bb682e9
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0003a0bf
Faulting process id: 0xcdcc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d32cb6db70fd71
Faulting application path: C:\windows\sysWOW64\wbem\wmiprvse.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL 
Server\100\Shared\svrenumapi100.dll
Report Id: 7ecb9ccf-40b3-47b3-956e-a8bfbd2ec0f3
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I can make a search to find application name within that big string, but Is there any better way to find crashed application?

Comment: You want to do it for all applications on your PC

Comment: no for certain applications, like all antivirus applications

Comment: You can split the x.Message by newline character into a list. Then, in that list, you can select the entry containing Faulting application path.

Comment: Correct Amit, I can certainly do that, just looking for other options

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best you can do is the `Source` property, however the documentation suggests that it is up to the logging application as to what it populates the source with:

> The event source indicates what logged the event. It is often the name
>   of the application or the name of a subcomponent of the application if
>   the application is large. Applications and services usually write to
>   (and therefore are sources for) the Application log or a custom log.
>   Device drivers usually write to the System log.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.source(v=vs.110).aspx

It might be that the type of event you are looking for is generated by the OS and correctly populates this, or it might not.

If you can guarantee that the application always runs on English language windows the string parse will be OK, if not it might be a bit harder.